# Categorizing cells based on a partial match

Tags: excel, lookup

**UPDATE: found an answer to my problem through this website: https://exceljet.net/formula/categorize-text-with-keywords**

I'm trying to categorize certain products based on the beginning of each product name. My first table is the look-up table below:

[image]

My second table currently looks like this:

[image]

And I want the end result of that second table to look like this:

[image]

What excel formula can I use to achieve the red column? I've tried scouring the internet, for the formula that best suits my need, but I can't figure it out. I've seen people throw out the =Lookup(Search()) function, but my formula needs to start with the key word, but just contain the keyword somewhere in the cell.

I've read many different forums, but I haven't been able to find one that answers a scenario similar enough to mine. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the first word of the Product Name is always matched to the product start, you can vlookup by just the 1st word. Assuming your product start is in column A, Categerization in Column B, Product Name in Column C, you can key in the formula in Column D:

```
=vlookup(left(C2,search(" ",c2)-1),A:B,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your vlookup 4th parameter to TRUE:
[image]

Note: formula as written can be drag/filled down from B2. Also your Category Table needs to be in A-Z sorted order.

HTH